# Trouble accessing network share from asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, shared-directory

I have an asp.net webform which will display a PDF file.  This pdf is stored on a network share on another server.  ***The share has read permissions for everyone.***

When I try to reference like \\server\sharename\file.pdf I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/NCLWeb' Application.
>   HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

I've also tried variation with "file://" in front, and reversing the slashes.  What am I doing wrong?

How should I properly reference this?

EDIT: I am testing the code using Visual Studio's built in development server.  Code usage includes:

```
Response.Redirect(@\\server\sharename\file.pdf);

ShowPdf1.FilePath = @\\server\sharename\file.pdf;
```

Where ShowPdf1 is a control which I've used to display pdf's in a browser before.

Comment: What account is your asp.net running as? Is it localservice for example?

Comment: Right now I"m testing on dev machine.  How to check?

Comment: Depends what server you are using :) Cassini, iis, iis express, etc. Perhaps first though: in exacty what code are you using `\\server\share` ? Can you show?

Comment: I'm curious about your answer to Marc's question.  Response.Redirect is a browser directive to fetch a different resource.  The asp.net worker process isn't actually touching the share, it's just telling the client to do so.  This of course begs the question of what it is you've told the browser to do, and whether that would be legit outside the context of your application.  The "ShowPdf1.Filepath" is suspect.  What happens if you don't include that?

Comment: Then my control won't even try to show the pdf.  I need to assign the filepath to the control.  The response.redirect() was just an additional testing test, I'm not using that in the real app.

Comment: I doubt the control is the real problem, as it has no trouble displaying files that are stored with the website's files.

Comment: Just because the share has read permissions doesn't mean the webserver has permissions to venture off the box. The webserver is sandboxed. If you're using the dev tools of VS then it _should_ work if you can open the file. But for IIS you'll have to configure something differently. Can you share the code for what ShowPdf1 does with the filepath? (also, MarcGravell is like a friggin boss on C# so I would really really listen to him [he writes this site])

Comment: I have no idea what the control does with the path, as I'm using a control from http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/PDF-View-Custom-Control.aspx (I will listen to anyone who has a suggestion.  I've seen Marc around this site, so I'm definately willing to try his suggestions.  I never meant to suggest otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that folder is a Virtual Directory. If you want to access any shared folder from your application you need to make a `Virtual Directory` of that Folder.

Comment: How to set this in my dev environment?

Comment: right click on shared folder --> Web Sharig and then make it Virtual Directory

Comment: Share is on Windows 2000 Server.  No Web Sharing option.

Comment: on your server, IIS Installed ?

Comment: The site is served from a different server.  Which server do I need to create the virtual directory on?

Comment: Which you have shared folder.

Comment: Yes, there is no option for Web Sharing there.

Comment: on that server, have you IIS Installed ?

Comment: No, IIS not installed on the the file server.  Never needed before.

Comment: You have to install to make that folder as Virtual Directory.

Comment: Making Virtual Directory, the folder is just like website, then in the browser we can directly access that file and that same path can be used in your website from where you are trying to access.

Comment: @MAW ~ I don't think that @Muhammad understands that you're doing this in the VS developer instead of IIS, so that there is no virtual directory.

Comment: Installed IIS, and selected Web Sharing.  No change on pdf display.

Comment: can you give the path to your application like.. http://YourServerIP/VirtualDirectoryname/filename.pdf, First try to access in browser and then assign that particular path in your application.

Comment: Now that works!  Are you suggesting I just use the IP instead of the UNC?

Comment: Actually, using ///servername/sharename/filename.pdf</pre> works, but prompts for a password.  Can I get rid of the password prompt?  Then it would be perfect.

Comment: Don't have idea about password prompt. but you can try to add aspnet user permission to that folder.

Comment: Ok, using 'http://servername/sharename/filename.pdf' and set the Virtual Directory to allow anonymous access.  Its displaying perfect and theres no password prompt!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net worker process needs permission to read network resources

check out article on code project(it was written in 2007) but it has basics written down step by step. 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UNC__Access_Network_file.aspx

here is KB from microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671

hope it helps

Comment: Won't changing the password to IUSR_MACHINENAME have side-effects?

Comment: Plus, even if I do all of this, it doesn't explain why my code fails in Visual Studio dev server.

Comment: @MAW yes, changing the password to IUSR_XXX will have side effects. I think there are other avenues to explore first.