# Error enumerating shared folder from ASP.NET web form

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions, webforms, intranet

I'm trying to run a method on the loading of a page which will search through a network shared folder and do a particular operation on all .tif files found.  Problem is I'm getting an error:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

FileInfo[] tifs = dir.GetFiles("*.tif", SearchOption.AllDirectories);   //Throws error.
```

> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path
>   '\server\sharename\folder\subfolder'
>   is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
>   used if the application is not
>   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity
>   will be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.

I've tried following these instructions, but I'm not able to add the specified account to the share's permissions.  What am I doing wrong?

See Related Question: [Trouble accessing network share from asp.net web form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5652326/456532)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to impersonate a user that does have access: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Using Web.Config impersonation didn't work for me, but this did: http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/